# Joint PDF over a uniform interval

Tags: probability, statistics

> A particle is emitted at time zero and undergoes a decay at some random time $S$. One of the decay products is then observed at time $T \geq S$. Suppose that $T$ has probability density function: $$ f_T(t) = \left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        \lambda^2te^{-\lambda t} & : t > 0\\
>        0 & : t \leq 0
>      \end{array}
>    \right.$$
>   For each $t > 0$ the conditional distribution of $S$ given that $T = t$ is uniform over the interval $(0, t)$.
>
> Find the joint probability density function of $S$ and $T$. Use this to ﬁnd the joint probability density function of $S$ and $W = T - S$. Determine if $S$ and $W$ are independent.

I think the best option is to try and condition $f_T(t)$ on $S$ to solve for $f_{S,T}(s,t)$, but I can't figure how to go about doing that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the first part the joint distribution of $S$ and $T$ is the product of $f_T(t)$ and $f_{S|T}(s|t)$, where defined. And you have both of these distributions.